# Does Ubuntu already support Intel Speed Shift?

Tags: intel, cpu

Does Ubuntu already support Intel Speed Shift? If not, when will it support Intel Speed Shift? I'm looking forward to use it with my new Skylake Mobile CPU.

Comment: What is  Intel Speed Shift?

Comment: So, does Speed Shift (available in Skylake and Kaby Lake), also known as Hardware P-States, actually work in Ubuntu 16.04 now that it is released? I am having a hard time finding any concrete information on this, despite tons of Google searches. It looks like [the Linux 4.5 kernel (or newer) may be required](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Linux-4.5-SKL-PState), but Ubuntu 16.04 was released on the 4.4 kernel? There's also a [January 2017 update](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=PState-CPUFreq-CLR-KBL) article.

Comment: @Pilot6 read more about Speed Shift here. http://www.anandtech.com/show/9751/examining-intel-skylake-speed-shift-more-responsive-processors TL;DR it hands clock speed control over to the CPU so the CPU can switch its own speeds 10x faster than the OS. Requires Skylake or newer CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Internal to the kernel the marketing name "Speed Shift" is known as HWP, Hardware P-States. HWP functionality will be in the very soon to be released Ubuntu 16.04. I do not know that status of any backports of recent HWP related changes to Ubuntu 15.10.